# How to set default angular application in asp.net core?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have multiple angular application inside an asp.net core application.
Now I want to set one of them as default. Let say When I run the app, it automatically goto angular home application.
Solution structure: SQL-> EntityFrameworkCore->.NET Core->Angular application( HomeApp, App1, App2....)

Right now, after I run the application, I have to go to URL and type : localhost:5000/home Togo to Angular Home application. Otherwise, it won't show anything.

I tried with asp.net core Map and UserSpaStaticFiels. 
In each angular app1, app2 index.html file I setup 
`<base href="/home/">`

And in startup.cs the code I setup like this:

```
<i>
 // For each angular application we want to host:

            app.Map(new PathString("/home"), home =>
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    StaticFileOptions clienthome = new StaticFileOptions()
                    {
                        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"home"))
                    };

                    home.UseSpaStaticFiles(clienthome);
                    home.UseSpa(spa =>
                    {
                        spa.Options.SourcePath = "home"; // spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
                        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start"); // it will use package.json & will search for start command to run
                    });

                }
                else
                {
                    // Each map gets its own physical path for it to map the static files to. 
                    StaticFileOptions clienthome = new StaticFileOptions()
                    {
                        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"home/dist"))
                    };
                    // Each map its own static files otherwise it will only ever serve index.html no matter the filename 
                    home.UseSpaStaticFiles(clienthome);

                    // Each map will call its own UseSpa where we give its own sourcepath
                    home.UseSpa(spa =>
                    {
                        spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 30);
                        spa.Options.SourcePath = "home";
                        spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = clienthome;
                    });
                }
            });
 </i>
```

My expectiation is : asp.net core should run only home application whenever I start visual studio without go to url and tyle localhost:5000/Home.

Answer (score 0):

Since the apps all have `base` hrefs it seems the cleanest approach would be to just add a redirect from `/` to `/home`.  Maybe something like...

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirect("/", "/home"));
```

Comment: Hey @Pace, thank for your answer.
I tried it, however, when I start localhost:5000, it still returns 404.